# How to get access all images of custom directory in twig template?

Tags: theming, 8, media

I intend to create a slideshow in front page of my theme to show **all images in custom directory**, I try to use [file_scan_directory](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!includes!file.inc/function/file_scan_directory/8.2.x) and [drupal_get_path](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_get_path/8.2.x) in below codes to get any non static images path and display that images automatically without any need to calling each one of them separately:
**Theme Name.theme:**

```
function MyThemeName_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
$mask = '/\.(?:jp[e]?g|gif|png)$/i';
$files = file_scan_directory(drupal_get_path('theme', 'Theme Name') . '/assets/img/orbit', $mask);
ksort($files);
$variables['files'] = $files;
}
```

**page.html.twig:**

```
{% for file in files %}
<img src="{{ file.uri }}" width="100%" height="100%" alt="{{ file.name }}"/>
{% endfor %}
```

I would be happy to hear what is the problem with the codes and what is the right way to load that slideshowe pictures?

Comment: Do you have the above code in a preprocess function? Such as THEME_NAME_preprocess_page(&$variables)

Comment: WRT to the best way to do something. I think it depends on your use case. Typically, I wouldn't go about this by calling pictures in the theme unless they are never to be edited by the client in the CMS and there isn't a need for other slideshows on the site. An example of how this could be accomplished is to create a custom slideshow block with an image field that allows X amount of images. This would allow for all the content to be controlled in the CMS, and other slideshows could be created.

Answer (score 0):

The path will be wrong, `file_scan_directory()` will return a relative path, you need to add the `base_path()`, you can set a variable in preprocess:

```
$variables['base_path'] = base_path();
```

So...

```
<img src="{{ base_path }}{{ file.uri }}" width="100%" height="100%" alt="{{ file.name }}"/>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your attention, but can you help me and explain a little more, whatever I try I get error only.

Comment: I don't know what you need me to explain.